# Allow website to be in public domain but require login view it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am using ASP/MVC to develop my websites, and I publish them on Azure (if that plays any role in this).

I often create websites that need to be verified by management, who are either traveling, not in the office/company network, and unable to view a local version of my website.

I currently publish them to some temporary dev instance on Azure, with a somewhat obscure URL... but they're still publicly accessible, and sometimes I'm creating content that should be considered secure, and I don't want indexable or discoverable by anyone.

What is an approach I can take to place all pages on my site behind a login? I'm thinking an entire authentication pattern would be overkill, as a simple user/password to view each page would suffice maybe? But maybe that is what authentication is. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Azure App Services platform (and it sounds like you should be if you are not - setup a shared instance, you can deploy lots of applications,each with a unique URL, to one single App Service plan), you can control this directly from your azure portal settings on the web application that you want to secure.

Open the blade for the web application you want to lock down and choose All Settings.  Next, choose the Authorization / Authentication option.  This allows you turn on your authentication and select from multiple providers to allow access such as Azure Active Directory (you manage the credentials), Microsoft Accounts, Facebook, etc.  You can make each application have a different set of credentials or all share one single set.  It is up to you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is the first I've attempted using AD within Azure. I just set it up for my test site, and it seems like it can be setup per app using the new Portal (portal.azure.com), but the AD needs to be managed using the old portal (manage.windowsazure.com). With that being said, it also looks like if I use the Azure AD, then it allows whoever is on the Azure AD user list access to the app. Guess this means management will need a Microsoft account and I'll need to add their account manually using the management portal? And anytime someone else wants to view it, I'll need to add them too?

Comment: @mariocatch - I have only recently switched away from the classic Web Roles to the App Service plans.  As a result, I am aware of this feature and its stated capabilities, but I cannot offer any actual implementation advice right now.  I have been looking into it, but not executed on it yet.  But what you said sounds correct.  And again, you could make Microsoft accounts for each app if you wanted instead (like appName@myDomain.com if you are an indy consultant).  That way, they don't need to do anything and you still get per app results.  This is my plan going forward.

Answer (score 1):

The process I tend to take to exposing things to 3rd parties is, instead of placing them on obscure URL, go as far as creating the Host Header, but don't create a DNS record for them. That way the client (or 3rd party) will need to add something to their host file to be able to see the site.

I don't really know azure, but the azure document [Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/) seems to suggest that you don't need to create the A DNS record if you don't have to.

With some systems (e.g. an e-commerce site) I believe the danger of getting real data into test systems, or something crawling a staging site and ending up on Google to out weigh the convenience of Joe Manager, and to have a more disastrous effect on a company.

Rolling out an authentication solution can cause issues if your site has some sort of membership / account behavior in it natively too.

As to stop things being indexed, it's not fool proof, but you can adjust [the robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html) file to recommend that bots don't crawl your site.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Comment: Explaining to someone in a management position who is traveling on the road how to modify the HOSTS file (and the machine is probably locked down anyways thanks to Least User Privledge principles) seems like a disastrous proposition.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but @Tommy is right :) I'm trying to make it as easy as possible for someone to view the site, but put it behind some sort of wall so it isn't indexed, or viewable by competitors before launch.

Comment: YMMV,  :-) With some systems (e.g. an e-commerce site) I believe the danger of getting real data into test systems, or something crawling a staging site and ending up on google to out weigh the convenience of Joe Manager.

Comment: Valid, but I would think there are easier methods in most cases.  (.htaccess files for instance if PHP based).  The HOSTS file on most machines will need admin access, which since Windows Vista, most end users no longer have in a company thanks to the UAC prompt.  Lastly, your dev sites should probably have a way to reset to a known state since you know, its a dev site :)  Fun conversation, I need more developer friends :D

Comment: @Tommy At the risk of going way OT in comments... :-) I wouldn't expose a dev site to anyone, everytime that happens its asking for trouble. My teams tend to deploy through multiple environments. Dev (**Development Work**, as noted v. unstable ;-) ) > Test (**System Test** / QA Teams validate) > UAT (**User Acceptence Testing**, internal staff, stakeholders, PMs, BAs) > OAT (**Operational Acceptance Testing**, like live) > Production (**Live stuff**), I would potentially expose either UAT or OAT, depending on the business requirement. I feel like I'm thinking bigger scale.

Comment: In the case of editing a HOST file, I wouldn't get Joe Manager to do it, I'd get _Application Support_ or _Infrastructure_ or _Ops_ to publish it on the internal DNS if it was within the organization. Tho, I would expect Barry ThirdParty to tho, because if they (for example) want to use our endpoints, they adhere to our security.